# hibernate postgres reverse engineering - how to make all tables visible to the reverse eng process?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a postgres 9.3 database named 'eugene':

```
eugene-# \dt
                List of relations
 Schema |         Name          | Type  | Owner
--------+-----------------------+-------+--------
 public | AspNetRoleClaims      | table | eugene
 public | AspNetRoles           | table | eugene
 public | AspNetUserAddresses   | table | eugene
 public | AspNetUserClaims      | table | eugene
 public | AspNetUserLogins      | table | eugene
 public | AspNetUserRoles       | table | eugene
 public | AspNetUsers           | table | eugene
 public | CartItem              | table | eugene
 public | Category              | table | eugene
 public | Order                 | table | eugene
 public | OrderLine             | table | eugene
 public | OrderShippingDetails  | table | eugene
 public | Product               | table | eugene
 public | Recall                | table | eugene
 public | WebsiteAd             | table | eugene
 public | __EFMigrationsHistory | table | eugene
 public | table1                | table | eugene
```

This database was created by converting a sql server database to postgres.

WhenI'm trying to describe any of the imported tables, I'm getting "no matching relations found":

```
eugene-# \dt Product
No matching relations found.
```

However, when I manually create a table in the same database, I can describe it just fine:

```
eugene-# \dt table1;
        List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  | Owner
--------+--------+-------+--------
 public | table1 | table | eugene
(1 row)
```

I'm trying to use hibernate reverse engineering to create the domain classes and mappings for this database.

The reverse process is only able to see the table, which I have created manually, but is unable to see all of the imported table (which is what I actually need).

What Postgres commands can I run, to make all tables in this database visible to my \dt command, as well as to the reverse engineering process?

Answer (score 0):

when reverse engineering hibenate seems to reject table names in postgres that have upper case letters.
I'm currently trying to not have to change a table name on postgres from Users to users to get hibernate to reverse engineer it.

Comment: i managed to fix mine using this link: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1006262